# SSIS Foreachloop container inquiry

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I have searched for this question everywhere and can't seem to find it so here we go.

I set up a Foreachloop container which is using the "Foreach File Enumerator" and in the Files section where you're naming the format of the file as well as a wildcard if you want to return only certain format files, I have in as F_*.csv which works fine, however, I can't seem to find a way to also return files who's name begin with D_. I'm aware this can get done by having 2 separate Foreachloop containers but is there any way it can be done in the same one so that it checks for both those files?

The reason I need this is because there are other csv files in that folder which don't begin with a D_ nor an F_ so I'm trying to exclude those.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can specify a regex in the "Files" criteria.  I would try to read in all files matching the broadest criteria ("*.csv") and then in the foreach loop, evaluate the filename into a variable and test the variable in the control flow. Add a sequence container to perform the desired ETL. On the connector to the sequence container, add a constraint for the filename test, if the test fails, do nothing, if it passes, move to the sequence container and perform actions.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm aware there is another workaround, just thought there would be an easier way to do this by adding additional wildcards in the Files section :) thanks for the reply though.